# How to use InfluxDB as an intermediate data storage

Tags: python, time-series, influxdb

I think InfluxDB is a really cool time series DB.

I am planning to use it as an intermediate data aggregator (collecting time based metrics from many sensors).

The data needs to be processed in "moving window" manner - when X samples received, Python based processing algorithm should be triggered.

What is the best wait to trigger the algorithm upon enough data aggregated? (I assume that polling with select queries is not the best option).

Is there any events I can wait on?

Thanks!
Meir

Answer (score 1):

Not using Python, but in my case i use continuous queries in InfluxDb to consolidate automatically data in one place/serie. Then i request every X seconds on the newly created serie using a time window to select my data. They are then draw using a standard framework (highcharts.js)
Maybe in your case you could wait for a predefined data volume before trigerring the push to the processing function.